# Is there a way to pass a function to component, accessed by useNavigate().navigate(/link_to_component)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**Using react react-router-dom v.6**

So, i'm using this construction to do routing in my app:

Component1

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
//something happened 
navigate('/link_to_component2', { state: { someVar: someVal} });
```

Component2

```
const {state} = useLocation();
const { someVar } = state; // Read values passed on state
```

My problem is that I want to pass a function from Component1 into Component2, like

Component1

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
var testFn = () => { // do something }
navigate('/link_to_component2', { state: { someFunc: testFn} });
```

When I do so my location state variable becomes empty, loosing even valid params.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can't do this, functions aren't serializable.

Comment: Serializable is like JSON.stringify: To send JSON between pages, people have to stringify first. Function is objects but I don't see any Object.stringify